# How to write math symbols in prettytable?

Tags: python-2.7, prettytable

I have the following prettytable headings:

```
row[0] = ('k','No', 'A', 'I', 'P', 'lambda', 'rho','Wq', 'Est. Cost', 'Time (s)')
t = PrettyTable(row[0])
```

In the above table, I want to write lambda, rho, and W^q in a math way. Is it possible here in the pretty table? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use any Unicode character you want in those strings. As this is Python 2, you probably need to write it as `u"λ"` – or, preferably, upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: @usr2564301 How about W^q? I knew this answer was gonna come and I added W^q so that a better solution is provided.